# What if a comment answers a question by a keyword/hint?

Tags: discussion, support, comments, answers

I have read "[What if a comment answers a question?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1731/what-if-a-comment-answers-a-question)" and in most cases I am supposed to ask the user who commented to give an answer.

And here is the instance
"[Timeline for overlapping (multi-year) events](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150530/timeline-for-overlapping-multi-year-events)". I have some choices (in order to remove the question from Unanswered-list):

- Ask @ClaudioFiandrino to give an answer. But there is nothing to explain! Why bother?
- Answer it with a MWE and some explanation. But the OP did not ask for it; they are satisfied with the comment.
- Close as **too broad**. This is how we treat "do it for me"-questions. But again, OP is satisfied with the comment.
- Close as **primarily opinion-based**, since theoretically one can accomplish it in many ways. But using `pgfgantt` seems to be the "consensus", not an opinion.
- Close as **duplicate**, to "[Gantt chart package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63877/gantt-chart-package)". This is subtle. Can we mark questions as duplicate just because they have the same answer?

What should I do now? I encounter this kind of questions pretty often, where either the OP needs to read the manual more carefully, or they just do not know the proper search terms, thereby failing to find an reference they seek.

Comment: I think the only answer with respect to similar unanswered questions on site would be: Use your best judgement what would be most helpful to users coming via google.

Comment: `Close as duplicate, to "Gantt chart package". This is subtle. Can we mark questions as duplicate just because they have the same answer?` That's exactly *why* we close questions as duplicates. :P Wording doesn't really count, if the topic is related and the answer solves the problem then it's a duplicate.

Comment: @Alenanno Yes, wording of the question content is not important. But wording of reasons for which we close is important. For new users, there is a huge difference between "**bad question! next!**" and "**try this answer from here**".

Comment: @Symbol1 Ah yes, certainly the attitude that we use counts. I totally agree on that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR**: I would vote to close this as a duplicate of [Gantt chart package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63877/5764) based on the OP's comment.

---

Here are my comments based on your choices:

> Ask @ClaudioFiandrino to give an answer. But there is nothing to explain! Why bother?

Based on what I can see, @ClaudioFiandrino is not affiliated with that post in any way. So, no.

> Answer it with a MWE and some explanation. But the OP did not ask for it; they are satisfied with the comment.

This doesn't really matter. If you want to add an answer then so be it. The mentioned comment by @JLDiaz is very generic and doesn't really suggest "ownership" over some form of answer... Technically comments aren't answers; we extend a *courtesy* towards the author of a possible answer-in-comment.

> Close as **too broad**. This is how we treat "do it for me"-questions. But again, OP is satisfied with the comment.

Yes, this is too broad, just by looking at the volume inside the answers to [Gantt chart package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63877/5764). Specifically there are small things that could be fine-tuned in terms of a Gantt chart, and without those specifics people will end up answering the question in its current and possibly be bombarded with additional fine-tuning requests...

> Close as **primarily opinion-based**, since theoretically one can accomplish it in many ways. But using `pgfgantt` seems to be the "consensus", not an opinion.

I would say no here, just because it's very broad. Perhaps there might be some overlap, but I don't think the question is posed in such a way that "it solicits primarily opinion-based answers".

> Close as **duplicate**, to "[Gantt chart package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63877/5764)". This is subtle. Can we mark questions as duplicate just because they have the same answer?

[Most certainly!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6458/5764) The [Guidelines for reviewing Close Votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180032/168244) mentions:

> Remember we are asking whether an [*answer* is found at the duplicate-linked question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166514/183887) moreso than whether the questions are identical. You should look at the question linked and verify that it has an answer to the question being proposed for closure. If it doesn't, it should not be closed as a duplicate. (You can't vote to close questions as duplicates when the proposed target has no upvoted or accepted answer(s).)

I use this approach regularly, since people approach problems from different angles, thereby leading to different questions. However, they're essentially after the same thing, which provides the common answer. Moreover, if others don't share your sentiment they can opt to vote differently; the SE network setup allows for that. ;)

Comment: So now I understand the banner "**This question already has an answer here:**". But "**This question has been asked *before* and already has an answer.**" may be inaccurate, since the answerer did not (need not to) check if they were answering the oldest one. [This](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287157/ugly-artifacts-with-pgf-blur-and-beamer-and-poppler) and [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226598/beamers-implicit-options-regarding-tikzpictures-and-shadows) is such a pair.

Comment: @Symbol1: True, the reference in the closure as a *duplicate* mentions the question. It seems fairly common across the network though, at least in my opinion, that duplicates tend to focus on a common goal and is therefore *answer*-centric.